# Unable to install 'next-stripe' dependency

Tags: next.js, stripe-payments

I am experimenting with the new next-stripe API (https://github.com/ynnoj/next-stripe) and because it is so new I have not found any usable documentation to my error.

To install the tool I ran: `yarn add next-stripe@beta` as they recommend. But when I try and use the import like so: `import NextStripe from 'next-stripe'` I receive the TypeScript error

```
"Could not find a declaration file for module 'next-stripe'. '/Users/user/example-app/medical/node_modules/next-stripe/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/next-stripe` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'next-stripe';`"
```

After I run the command "npm I --save..." as the error mentions, I get a series of errors in the command line which have to do with it not being found (404).

In my package.json I have these two packaged installed:

```
"next": "^11.0.0",
"next-stripe": "^1.0.0-beta.9",
```

So some version of it did clearly install.

I would appreciate any assistance getting this up, and if there are any specific recommendations for which package number to use if this is a common issue.

EDIT: When I add `declare module 'next-stripe'`; I get the error

`Invalid module name in augmentation. Module 'next-stripe' resolves to an untyped module at '/Users/user/Desktop/example-app/node_modules/next-stripe/index.js', which cannot be augmented.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the types for the package

---

#### Check @types

---

Check is someone has made the types for the package and install that package like the following

```js
npm i -D @types/next-stripe
```

---

#### Delcare module

If `@types/next-stripe` don't exist then you need to declare it as a module yourself

1. Declare the module - only one module can be declared in the file

**index.d.ts** - must contain .**d.ts** in the name

```js
declare module 'next-stripe';
```

2. Tell typescript to include the file

**tsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "include": [
    "./index.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I have edited my question to show the error this gives. I should also note that my index.d.ts file is inside of my node_modules file, if that matters.

Comment: is your file named index.d.ts - it has to have the .d.ts ? Also, you cannot have more than one module declared in that file. Make sure the declared module matches the package.json - I cannot see your package.json but it appears that it should be  'next-stripe'